# How to get the index of the value in a list closest to x?

Tags: sass

Let's say I have a list:

```
$list: 0.67, 1.02, 1.2, 1.4, 1.8, 2
```

And I also have `$x: 1.067`

How can I get the index of the value in `$list` closest to `$x`, let's call this `$y`?

I've tried a few things but none of which are reliable, and could easily fail depending on the values in the list:

```
@each $value in $list {
    @if round($value * 10) == round($x * 10) {
        $y: index($list, $value);
    }
}
```

Of course this is terrible as it will only match the first value that is somewhat similar to `$x`, not *the* value that is closest, and will fail if no numbers are within 1 decimal place of `$x`.

Is this possible with Sass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just iterate over the list once like this:

```
$list: 0.67, 1.02, 1.2, 1.4, 1.8, 2;
$x: 1.067;
$bestValue: 99999;
$bestIndex: -1;
@for $i from 1 through length($list) {
  $value: abs($x - nth($list, $i));
  @if $value < $bestValue {
    $bestValue: $value;
    $bestIndex: $i;
  }
}
@error $bestIndex;
```

This is a common pattern, you define a "best index" and "best value" (initially with some really bad number) and then iterate once over the list. For each element you check if its value is "better". If so, you update your value and index.

Comment: Thanks, this does indeed seem to work. I don't really understand what's going on though, would you mind quickly explaining?

Answer (score 0):

You could subtract x from each of the values and sort by the absolute result of your subtraction.